# gifencoder on Node throws TypeError

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to follow the instructions for [npm `gifencoder`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gifencoder)

I have the following file structure:

Directly under my project folder, I have a `tempDir` directory. The `node_modules` directory is a sister directory.

Below is the code I'm trying to execute

```
var gifConvert = function(){
    var encoder = new GIFEncoder(300,300);
    pngFileStream('tempDir/*.png') //this is where the console tells me the error is occurring
    .pipe(encoder.createReadStream({repeat:-1, delay:430, quality: 10}))
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('../public/generatedCoins/coin_12345.gif'));

}
```

When I run this I get an error saying dest.on('unpipe, onunpipe) . . . TypeError:undefined is not a function.

I suspect it is how I'm typing in the directory but I have tried all sorts of combinations and get the same result.

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the fine manual](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gifencoder#streaming-api---duplex-piping-with-writes), you need to create a *writable* encoder stream:

```
pngFileStream('tempDir/*.png')
.pipe(encoder.createWriteStream({repeat:-1, delay:430, quality: 10}))
.pipe(...);
```